# MongoDB finding an item in an array and how to index properly

Tags: mongodb

I have documents stored like so:

```
{
    ...
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "123456",
            "username" : "John",
            "address" : "fake st",
        }
    ],
...
}
```

What is the best way of being able to retrieve all the documents with the username "john". Also, what are the proper ways of indexing this for performance considering its inside an array. Do I want to index "users", or is there a better way? This is inside a database with 50+ million documents.

Comment: Make a users model and query for users by name with User.find({ username: "john" }, function(err, users) {...})

Comment: Are you talking about all of these documents where the users-array contains at least one "John" or each array entry where `username=John`

Comment: All the documents where they contain at least one "john". I think I figured it out, so my main concern is how to create the index for this in the best possible manner. Users actually can only ever contain one element (not my choice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all the documents which contain at least one "john" in the users array, use `db.collection.find({"users.username":"john"});`

To make this faster, create an index with `db.collection.createIndex({"users.username":1});`. Indexes in MongoDB can reach inside arrays and index individual array entries (this is called a [multikey index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/)).

Comment: Thanks! How does this differ from simply creating an index on `users`? Would that index the entire array?

Comment: @Wilson That would index each complete array entry as one separate key. So it would only help when you query for a complete user object (providing id, username **and** address).